# python3: sum (union) of dictionaries with "+" operand raises exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictview

I'd like to avoid the update() method and I read that is possible to merge two dictionaries together into a third dictionary using the "+" operand, but what happens in my shell is this:

```
>>> {'a':1, 'b':2}.items() + {'x':98, 'y':99}.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#84>", line 1, in <module>
    {'a':1, 'b':2}.items() + {'x':98, 'y':99}.items()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'
>>> {'a':1, 'b':2} + {'x':98, 'y':99}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    {'a':1, 'b':2} + {'x':98, 'y':99}
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: "I read that is possible to merge two dictionaries together into a third dictionary using the "+" operand" - No, it is not. I have no idea where you read it, but it's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dicts = {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'x':98, 'y':99}
new_dict = dict(sum(list(d.items()) for d in dicts, []))
```

or

```
new_dict = list({'a':1, 'b':2}.items()) + list({'x':98, 'y':99}.items())
```

On Python 3, `items` doesn't return a `list` like in Python 2, but a [dict view](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views). If you want to use `+`, you need to convert them to `list`s.

You're better off using `update` with or without `copy`:

```
# doesn't change the original dicts
new_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}.copy()
new_dict.update({'x':98, 'y':99})
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting from Python 3.5 the idiom is:

```
{**dict1, **dict2, ...}
```

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/